# Ensure custom module migration has finished entirely in Orchard CMS?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, migration, orchardcms

I have created a custom module in 1.9.1 that inserts several tables into the database via a migration file as per normal protocol.  What I've found, is, Orchard erroneously declares [...in my opinion] modules as "Enabled" too early: IFeatureEventHandler > Enabled, for when this is triggered the migration session has not even finished [i.e. the commit hasn't occurred and your tables will not be in the database, even though Orchard's versioning system / enabled etc. will say otherwise.]

Therefore any subsequent code dependant on such tables will obviously throw an error.

Does anyone have a foolproof method for ensuring the migration/s have run successfully and are indeed committed into the DB [i.e. after AutomaticDataMigrations (from Orchard.Framework) has finished] so that I can then run further code obviously dependent on such tables?

I have debugged SessionLocator.cs high and low for any ideas, but the entity types seem to get created sporadically and I cant come up with a good hook to let me know when my Module is in session?

I really don’t want to separate my code that needs to fire immediately after the migration into a separate module that would then be dependent on the current one, and even if I did, I'm not confident it would work either.
[Currently I'm manually updating the UpdateFrom# method once the initial migration has truly committed.]

Thanks for your time and any suggestions.

UPDATE:
As this is most likely a bug, here is some temp code i'm using to get me by ;)

```
namespace Test.Infrastructure
{
    public class Shell : IOrchardShellEvents {
        private readonly IDbMap _dbMap;
        public static bool EaActivate { get; set; }

        public Shell(IDbMap dbMap)
        {
            _dbMap = dbMap;
        }

        public static bool EaModuleState(bool state)
        {
            return EaActivate = state;
        }

        //IOrchardShellEvents:
        public void Activated() {
            if (EaActivate) {
                _dbMap.AlterDB();
                EaActivate = false;
            }
        }

        public void Terminating() { }
    }

    public class FeatureMod : IFeatureEventHandler {
        public void Installing(Feature feature) { }
        public void Installed(Feature feature) { }
        public void Enabling(Feature feature) { }
        public void Enabled(Feature feature) {
            if (feature.Descriptor.Id == "Test") {
                Shell.EaModuleState(true);
            }
        }
        public void Disabling(Feature feature) { }
        public void Disabled(Feature feature) { }
        public void Uninstalling(Feature feature) { }
        public void Uninstalled(Feature feature) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: That might be an issue, yes, in border cases. You should probably file a bug, to be sure. 
Do you have a reliable repro case?

Comment: Ok - thanks Bertrand - will do.  As a temporary measure til then i'll update my question with some hack'ish code i'm using to get me by; may help others. Cheers